# Combined ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections

I'm looking for a concurrent collection which can be accessed from both sides. I want to achieve the following:

- Some producers add items
- The client shall be able to display the last *n* produced items
- The collection shall only contain elements produced within the last *x* hours

So I need to access the top of the list (FIFO) for displaying the last *n* items, but I also need to access the end of the list (LIFO) to prune elements older than *x* hours continuously.

Comment: Why you cannot use both? Wrap them to one class with `Add` method, which will add given item to both

Comment: @Fabio: You will have to synchronize access to two individual collections using some kind of locking mechanism but then you might just as well use a single list guarded by a lock which should be a solution to the problem. However, this question specifically mentions a _concurrent collection_.

Comment: @Fabio The Stack would fill up and there would be no way to remove old items.

Comment: A FIFO data structure always has its oldest item at the beginning. So the first item in the queue is the oldest not the last. To remove items that exceed a certain timespan you would have to validate each item you dequeue before display or remove the range of items periodically from head to tail. Have you checked out the BlockingCollection which allows the producer to signal end of production? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287247(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It sounds like a double ended queue - but I don't think C# has one out of the box. Wonder if this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/01/22/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue/

Comment: @BionicCode In my understanding the `BlockingCollection` only adds blocking and boundaries to the normally non-blocking concurrent lists. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes. Your problem sounded like Producer-Consumer problem. I thought maybe you could need the features. But I think I got you wrong because you mixed up FIFO with LIFO. If you are producing 10 items but only want to display the last 3 then you would need a LIFO not FIFO. This means you are always picking the latest items. You still could validate the lifetime of each item before display. Or you have to implement it yourself by extending an existing concurrent collection by adding members like TakeFirst and TakeLast using a backup collection. Or use LINQ  FirstOrDefault and LastOrDefault.

Comment: @ManuelFaux, you can use `MemoryCache` for removing "expiring" items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The client shall be able to display the last n produced items

That is not about removing items. I assume you want them to stay in there after having been displayed. 
So you don't really want the  LIFO part.

When the number of items isn't too big you can use a ConcurrentQueue and ToArray() to get a snapshot (and use only the first n items).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `MemoryCache` class, which is thread-safe and provide built-in functionality for removing "expired" items.

I have created a class for keeping saved value and timestamp

```
public class SavedItem<T>
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Collection class will have two methods: one for adding and one for retrieving N-amount of last items

```
public class ExpiredCollection
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache;

    private readonly int _hoursLimit;

    public ExpiredCollection(int hoursLimit)
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache("sample");
        _hoursLimit = hoursLimit;
    }

    public void Add<T>(T value)
    {
        var item = CreateCacheItem(value);
        var policy = CreateItemPolicy();

        _cache.Add(item, policy);
    }

    private CacheItem CreateCacheItem<T>(T value)
    {
        var addedValue = new SavedItem<T>
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
            Value = value
        };
        // Create unique key to satisfy MemoryCache contract
        var uniqueKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return new CacheItem(uniqueKey, addedValue);
    }

    private CacheItemPolicy CreateItemPolicy()
    {
        // This will set a time when item will be removed from the cache
        var expirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(_hoursLimit);
        var offset = new DateTimeOffset(expirationTime);

        return new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = offset
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetLast<T>(int amount)
    {
        return _cache.Select(pair => (SavedItem<T>)pair.Value)
                     .OrderBy(item => item.Timestamp)
                     .Select(item => item.Value)
                     .Take(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: For performance I would use "SkipWhile()" since "Where()" iterates over the full collection to compare each item. "ConcurrentBag" is unordered. This would require to search through the whole bag to find the item that was added last by comparing dateTime of each. If you would use a list or array you would just take from the end to get the latest. Now you are able to move linear through the collection using SkipWhile(). And Take() or TakeWhile() do not modify the source collection. You have to remove the items by yourself or your backupcollection will contain outdated data and grow and slow down

Comment: @BionicCode, updated answer with another approach which should handle removing "expired" values.